# How to keep NSTimer alive?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, nstimer

I have 2 viewControllers in my app, from first view when i navigate to next one there is a button named startTimer with a timer action as selector method on Click of startTimer the timer starts up in **HH:mm:ss** format, i am not invalidating timer,but When i go back to 1st viewController and again if i come to again 2nd viewController and if i press startTimer button the timer again starts from 0, but i want it to be retained the previous value,how can i achieve this? i know that since i'm loading again the viewController the nib will be loaded freshly to memory but how can i retain the timer label and timer value?
Any help is appreciated in advance.thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You've broken MVC (Model-View-Controller) by putting your data into your view controller. Moreover, you're asking a mechanism with no solid promises about time (`NSTimer`) to keep track of time for you. `NSTimer` does not fire *exactly* at the interval you request. It can fire at any arbitrary point after that interval. <strike>Using `NSTimer` as a stopwatch will almost always lose time (sometimes quite a lot of time, particularly if there's a scrollview around).</strike> (That last bit is overstated. A repeating timer schedules itself correctly so won't usually lose time. You'll just lose time if a repeat is completely skipped, which can happen during long scrolls or other things that can keep timers for firing for a full second.)

Create a new model object to hold the stopwatch information. Let's call it `Stopwatch`. Assuming you need it to be startable and stoppable, it needs an `NSTimeInterval accumulatedTime` property and an `NSDate lastStarted` property (you could also make `lastStarted` an `NSTimeInterval` if you like). So to start the stopwatch, you set `lastStarted` to "now." To stop the stopwatch, you clear `lastStarted` and move the current accumulated time to `accumulatedTime`. To find out the current time, you add `accumulatedTime` to `now - lastStarted`.

OK, now that you have that, what can you do with it? You can pass it to your view controllers and they can ask "what's the current stopwatch value?" They can start and stop it as they like.

Now your view controller would like to update its display every second, so you have a timer that does that. Every second it asks the stopwatch, "what's the current time" and it displays it. But it does not *set* the time. It just asks.

BTW, you can also use KVO on `Stopwatch`, but it's a little trickier, since `Stopwatch` needs to run its own timer to send out the change notifications. I generally find this more trouble than its worth.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do like that, this way every time you load the view containing the NSTimer, a new NSTimer object is created and the old one is still in the memory since you're not invalidating it.

The best way is that you must put NSTimer in the Application Delegate and then start it only when you first time load that View Controller.

For achieving this, you must put a flag to check that the View is loaded first time or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the NSTimer is one of your instance variable, I guess you could do a check to see if it is allocated or not.

```
//NSTimer *timer;  declare this in your interface

if (timer==nil)
{
   // allocate timer
}
//Do nothing if it is allocated all ready
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to mantain the second view controller as an ivar of your first view controller. This way, you can instantiate it just once and your NSTimer will remain in memory.

However, if you want to maintain your style, you should save the current time in any kind of preferences (look at `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` or create your own singleton class). Then in view did load method from your second view controller, load that value and add it as an offset for your timer.

Hope to help!